# Java Bubble Sort - Infinite Loop

Tags: java

The issue is that I am getting an infinite loop when I try to run.

> boolean flag = true;
>
> ```
>    do {
>        flag = false;
>        for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; ++i) {
>            if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
>                swap(list, i, i + 1);
>                flag = true;
>            }
>            
>        }
>    }
>    while (flag == true);
> ```

EDIT: I should have said that the problem IS with the while loop, but it's due to what is happening in the for loop.
The swap function works because I have used it for other things before
Here is the array list if that is really needed.

```
int [] list;
list = new int[5];
list[0] = 4; 
list[1] = 5;
list[2] = 12;
list[3] = 9;
list[4] = 3;
```

Comment: maybe, `swap` does not swap?

Comment: or there are equal elements.

Comment: I can not see how `for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; ++i) {` can result in a endloop loop as neither `i` or `list.length` is being changed externally.  So maybe the problem IS with the while loop.

Comment: @Carlos nah, that should not matter

Comment: @Scary I would expect flag is always true. i.e. a swap is always attempted.

Comment: try displaying the list prior to the while.

Comment: @BevynQ The OP states, `The problem is with the for loop, not the do while loop` and I am stating that I do not believe that this is the case.  The value of `flag` does not affect the `for` loop

Comment: There is not enough information here to discover your problem post more of your code, the list creation, what is in the list and your swap function

Comment: The problem can't be with the for loop. Unless you created an array of infinite length. Which would most likely result a contract @ Google. In other words, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: i dont get why people have marked this question down.

Comment: @SlipperySeal probably because of his comment with where the error is. As well as not posting the actual relevant code for the error.

Comment: Added the code for the array.
@BevynQ I believe you are right but am not sure how to fix this

Comment: @Dima yeah youre right.  My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay we have all your code besides swap, so I have replace your swap with what I can assue it does. and everything here runs correctly, no infinite loop. So it is **most likely the swap method that causes your problem**.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int [] list;
    int temp;   
    list = new int[5];
    list[0] = 4; 
    list[1] = 5;
    list[2] = 12;
    list[3] = 9;
    list[4] = 3;
    boolean flag = true;

    do {
        flag = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; ++i) {
                if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {

                    //replaces your swap
                    temp = list[i];                
                    list[i] = list[i+1];
                    list[i+1] = temp;

                    flag = true;
                }

            }
        }
        while (flag == true);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
}
```

output = `[3, 4, 5, 9, 12]`

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be swap because you didn't test every single test case, but the it is very likely

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas yeah that's more what I mean